# Inner product on direct sum of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two different Hilbert spaces then how can we define the inner product on $H_1\oplus H_2$

Comment: $H_{1}\times H_{2}$ is better notation for your situation.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, why is that better? I'm studying an article where I'm sure that the particular inner product acts on the space $H_1\oplus H_2$, but the author is writing $H_1\otimes H_2$. In this way, your comment would be pretty important for me.

Comment: $H_1 \times H_2$ is the Cartesian product, which is a collection of ordered pairs. You can put an inner product on this Cartesian product. What does your notation $H_1\oplus H_2$ mean for different Hilbert spaces? Please define it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

$$\langle (x,y),(z,w)\rangle_{H_1\oplus H_2}=\langle x,z\rangle_{H_1}+\langle y,w\rangle_{H_2}$$