# Orthonormality of the yielded basis of the direct sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, direct-sum

if V is the direct sum of two subspaces then is true that by adjoining any two orthonormal basis of of our resp. subspaces yields an orthonormal basis of V?
it should be clear from the context i'm only interested in the orthonormality of the yielded basis

Comment: Let's see if I understand the problem: you begin with $U=V\oplus W$ and then you ask whether the union of any orthonormal basis of $V$ and an orthonormal basis of $W$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$. Is that the question? If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: how to prove orthogonality between vectors of V and W in the resp. orthonormal bases

Comment: At least according to Jose answer it is a matter of definitions. If you define $V=U\oplus W$ where $V=U+W$ and $U\cap W =\{0\}$ then as Jose showed this is not enough. However when talking about inner product spaces sometimes one assumes that $V=U\oplus W$ also requires that  $\left<u,w\right>=0$ for all $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.

Comment: Perhaps this question is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726398/inner-product-on-direct-sum-of-hilbert-spaces

Comment: i have yet to study hilbert spaces and i'm already satisfied with the counter-example sir josé provided

Comment: You can replace Hilbert space with an inner product space in this question. The point is that usually the inner product of a direct sum is defined such that $W=U^\perp$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Suppose that you are working on $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with its usual inner product. Take $U=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $W=\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $\{(1,0)\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$, $\left\{\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)\right\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$, and $\left\{(1,0),\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)\right\}$ is *not* an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: this is a proof for Characterization of normal operators when F= R from the book linear algebra done right third edition, as you could see he didn't define an orthonormal basis of his vector space and then assigned corresponding vectors from that basis to his direct sum decomposition which makes wonder that this proof might be flawed/ https://ibb.co/kqrDM4D

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that proof, of course. But in that proof, $W=U^\perp$, which is something you did not include in your question.

Comment: oh my bad i didn't even take that into consideration when i asked the question ;-; so yea it obviously holds by definition